# SQL - How to fetch the most recent entry between two different tables? (timestamp isn't getting stored)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an Ongoing project, where i am dealing with `quotes`, The DB structure is not well organised and i can't do much changes in DB schema to fix it.

In the Databse:

- Two type of Quotes and getting saved in two different tables.
- lets say `regular_quotes` and `premium_quotes` are two table.
- the situtation is, No one table is storing `date/time`, there is not any column realted to `created_at` or no alternate `column` which stores `date/time`
- And I have to check from those two tables which table has the most recent entry.

**Table1**
`regular_quotes`

```
id | name | quoteno | status  | .....|
------------------------------------------
1  | name1| RQ-909099 | pending  | .....|
2  | name2| RQ-800099 | pending  | .....|
3  | name3| RQ-965099 | approved | .....|
```

**Table2**
`premium_quotes`

```
id | name | quoteno | status  | .....|
------------------------------------------
1  | name1| PQ-209099 | pending  | .....|
2  | name2| PQ-300099 | pending  | .....|
3  | name3| PQ-965099 | pending  | .....|
```

**What i have done is:**

- created a new table `recent_quote_meta`
- having colument like, `id`, `quote_id`, `quote_type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`
- whenever qny quote is getting created, i am storing that in `recent_quote_meta` with `quote_id`
- from this i am getting recent `quote_id` and `quote_type`, based on this i am fetching and displaying quotes accrodingly

But The situation is, They don't want me to do any changes in DB. And i don't think it can done with ongoing scenario.

Is there a way by which it can be possible to get most recent quote those tables? it can be either `regular_quotes` or either `premium_quotes`

Thanks!

Comment: Get a pencil and some paper and log the highest id at the end of each day.. assuming of course id is auto_increment

Comment: I got your point. But our use case isn't fetching the latest quote from both of the table. the most recent quotes between those two table is need to get.

Comment: Not with you, can't you log for both tables for some reason?

Comment: There comes a time when all other attempts have failed, when you have to admit your DB design was not fit for purpose. At that point (now) you have to bite the bullet and redesign your table(s)

Comment: @P.Salmon i suggested them initially, but i cant do that on my own. i needs approval.

Comment: OK then your just going to have to go back to whoever initiated this request and tell them it's not possible explaining why and let them sort it out or bump it up to your line manager.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes. Using this reference to make them understand the situation. Thanks for your time and response (y)

Comment: 'Using this reference to make them understand' - Office politics being what they are I suggest you don't give the opportunity to deflect by telling them you have sought out of house support.

Answer (score 0):

Without any timestamp columns, it is really not possible to determine which of the two tables has the most recent quote entry. We can try some tricks but your stituation will determine if they can be trusted.

One way is, you can maybe check if the IDs are assigned sequentially, and since you know the latest ID in both tables, you can compare them to determine which table has the latest quote. For example, if the latest `id` in the `regular_quotes` table is `3`, and the latest `id` in the `premium_quotes` table is `5`, you can conclude that the latest quote is in the `premium_quotes` table.

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS latest_regular_quotes_id FROM regular_quotes;


SELECT MAX(id) AS latest_premium_quotes_id FROM premium_quotes;
```

These will return the highest ID value in each table. You can compare the two values to determine which table has the latest quote from which `id` has the highest value.

Ideally you may want to tell your Admin to fix this.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that approach isn't the solutions. I have already asked admin for this.

Comment: you cannot check the maximum ID? admin won't allow that?